# Редактирование массива

Tags: алгоритм, php7

Есть массив:

```
$arr = [
    's' => [
        's1' => [
            'h' => [
                'Значение',
                'Какой-то текст'
            ],
        ]
    ],
    'l' => [
        'l1' => [
            'h' => [
                'Значение',
                'Какой-то текст'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Как написать редактор массива, так, чтобы каждый ключ и значение было в `input`?
Никак не могу понять, как написать алгоритм, ведь массив может быть разный, а также разные вложенности.
Как написать, алгоритм так, чтобы перебирало любой массив и добавляло в `input`?
Помогите пожалуйста, люди добрые.

Ну так, чтобы после изменения полей, массив можно было собрать и перезаписать.
Выглядеть должно так:

**s** (input)

- s1 (input)

  - h (input)

    - (Значение внутри input) напротив (Какой-то текст также внутри input)

Comment: Предлагаю сконвертировать в JSON и использовать готовый визуальный редактор JSON [типа такого](http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/)

Comment: @TotalPusher, Вы дали реализацию `javascript`. Чего не делается в принципе и в метках я его не указывал. Конвертировать ничего не нужно, нужен отдельный механизм, который будет распознавать вложенности и конец перебора массивов. Я не могу понять, как мне сделать так, чтобы вывод был именно в инпутах, только ключи, когда массив, и если нет массивов, значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто.

```
function edit(array $array) {
    static $i = 1;
    if (!$array) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo $key, '<br>';
            ++$i;
            edit($value);
        } else {
            echo $value, '<br>';
        }
        echo'<br>';
    }
}
```